# How do i use cursor to print new things i added to table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to write SQL trigger in postgresql.

```
create trigger add_car on samochod
after insert
as
begin
    declare k_inserted cursor
    for select car_model, mileage from inserted
    declare @car_model(30), @mileage varchar(30)

    open k_inserted
    fetch next from k_inserted into @car_model(30), @mileage varchar(30)

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        print 'Added car: '
        print 'Model: ' + @car_model
        print 'Mileage: ' + @mileage 
        fetch next from k_inserted into @car_model(30), @mileage varchar(30)
    end

    close k_inserted
    deallocate k_inserted
end

INSERT INTO car(car_model, mileage)
VALUES  ('Audi', 15011646);
```

That trigger actually works for me. Then i tried in postgresql.

```
create function add_car()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
as
$$
declare
    car_model varchar(30);
    mileage varchar(30);
    k_inserted cursor for select new.car_model, new.mileage from car;
begin
    open k_inserted;
    fetch next from k_inserted into car_model, mileage;

    while (FOUND)
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Added car: ';
        RAISE NOTICE 'Marka: %', car_model; 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Mileage: %', mileage;
        fetch next from k_inserted into car_model, mileage;
    end LOOP;
    close k_inserted;
    return new;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER add_car
after INSERT on car
for each row EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_car();
```

It works but it prints me 6 times the same thing (i have 6 cars in my table)
How can I fix it so that it prints as many times as the cars I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your trigger as `for each row` so there is no need for a loop or a select "from inserted" (something that SQL Server doesn't have). The trigger will be called once for each row you insert, so just print the values from the `new` record

```
create function add_car()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
as
$$
begin
  RAISE NOTICE 'Added car: ';
  RAISE NOTICE 'Marka: %', new.car_model; 
  RAISE NOTICE 'Mileage: %', new.mileage;

  return new;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

If you do want a statement level trigger to mimic SQL Server's behaviour, you can do the following:

A trigger function using the `inserted` transition table:

```
create function add_car()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
as
$$
declare
  l_row record;
begin
  for l_row in select * from inserted
  LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Added car: ';
      RAISE NOTICE 'Marka: %', l_row.car_model; 
      RAISE NOTICE 'Mileage: %', l_row.mileage;
  end LOOP;
  return new;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the corresponding definition of a statement level trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_car
  after INSERT on car
  REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS inserted
  for each statement EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_car();
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to use cursor.

Comment: @tadziuuuuu: no you don't especially not in a row level trigger - there is no table to select from. You only have the one row that the trigger fired

Comment: my task was to replace the sql trigger with postgresql.using the cursor is part of this task

Comment: If the task is to migrate the trigger code, my answer shows how to do it. Using a cursor is a bad idea (and it was in SQL Server to begin with). Do not blindly implement approaches from SQL Server in Postgres - that won't work. Postgres is very different to SQL Server and in most cases if you try to copy SQL Server solutions you will wind up with a very inefficient and non-scalable solution. The solution in my answer **is** the way to do it in Postgres. You need to migrate your mindset too.

Comment: Then you didn't create the trigger as I showed you (`referencing ... for each statement`)

Comment: sorry, my bad. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can i do it also with deleted cars? It shows me this: NEW TABLE can only be specified for an INSERT or UPDATE trigger.

Comment: @tadziuuuuu: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) you need to use the `old` record in DELETE row level triggers or use `REFERENCING OLD AS ..` for statement level triggers: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html